# Access self objects and decorator parameters within a decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-class

I have a decorator method within a class and I'm trying to add parameters for when the method is called e.g:

```
@log.diagnostic(DEBUG=True)
def exmp_function():
    '''
    Some stuff
    '''
```

Then, within the decorator I need to access both the parameters passed (e.g. DEBUG), as well as a number of self.attributes:

```
    def diagnostic(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.DEBUG = args[0]
        def error_wrap(function): # DEBUG here isn't recognised
            @functools.wraps(function)
            def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
                try:
                    result = function(*args,**kwargs)
                    self.status = 'OK'
                except Exception as error:
                    self.status = 'ERROR'
                    result = 'Error'
                finally:
                    self.to_File([self.file,self.status,self.DEBUG]) # self.file is defined outside
                    return result
            return wrapper
        return error_wrap
```

Currently, the `self.` attributes are correct, however, the decorator parameter is always the parameter of the last decorator to be called. I think this is because the outside wrapper is called for each decorator and then self.DEBUG is left as the last decorators parameter.

I therefore need to find a way to pass my DEBUG parameter down two layers. But I cannot find a way to do this.

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Can you update the question with sufficient parts of the `log` decorator so I can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Just use a different name for the inner args and kwargs. Then they won't shadow the outer ones and you have access to the outer ones as closure variables.